# Continuously finding the next element jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to extract each letter out of a table that is inside of a span. Here's what I have:

```
<?php
    $y='A';
    $c=0;
    $z=0;
    echo "<table id=tableexample>";
    while ($z<100){
        $c=0;
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($c<3) {
            if (isset($names[$z])){              
                echo "<td><span id=boldinfo>".$y."</span><br></td>";    
            }      
            $y++;
            $c++;
            $z++;
        }

    }
    echo("</tr>\n");
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

So I have multiple repeating `span` classes, and I want to use jQuery/JS to be able to parse through them and get each value.

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.c3-legend-item-event').mouseover(function(){
        var colorKeyLength = $(this).closest("g").attr('class').length;
        var colorKey = $(this).closest("g").attr('class')[colorKeyLength-1];
        var colorKey2 = '';

        while (colorKey != colorKey2){
            colorKey2 = $( "table" ).find('#boldinfo').text();

        }

    });
});
```

In the JS, the variable `colorKey` will be either A,B,C,.., or Z. In the PHP, the variable `y` does the same thing and will increment its letter as it loops through.

My problem is being able to parse through the loop that has identical span classes with different text. I'm not sure how I'd word it. I know I can use next(), but I'm not sure how I'd do that through multiple iterations. I'm trying to make it so when I hover over something, the cell that contains the same letter as colorKey will be hightlighted in a color different from the rest of the cells.

Comment: do you end up with multiple spans with the same id?

Comment: Yes, but using $("table").find("#theid") should get around that problem. (still poor design though)

Comment: Yes shafeen. Is there any way to just keep skipping to the next `span` element without having to uniquely name them all?

Comment: the :contains selector might help in this situation (it would remove the while loop.) Alternatively, .filter could be used.

Comment: Thank you @KevinB , I got it working, sort of. It highlights the appropriate cell, but then it stays that color permanently.

Comment: You have multiple spans with the same id. You should use the attribute `class="boldinfo"` instead of `id` and select them all with a jQuery selector `$('#tableexample .boldinfo').each(function(i){ var spanElement = $(this); /* do something */ });`

Comment: @John I elaborated a bit more in my answer. Don't forget to vote up if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you will only be looking at spans in the format `<span id="boldinfo"></span>` (I would encourage using class here instead of id), a simple jQuery selector like `$("span[id=boldinfo]")` can be used to just loop through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `id` is supposed to be related to a unique element, you should use the attribute `class` instead. It is also not a good practice to set an attribute without quotes (it will only work if you have a single attribute). Here's the modifications:

```
<?php

    $y = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $z = 0;

    // could also be "<table id=\"table\">" 
    echo '<table id="tableexample" ' .
    'cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" ' .
    'style="width:100%;">';

    while ($z < 100)
    {
        $c = 0;
        echo '<tr>';

        while ($c < 3)
        {
            if (isset($names[$z]))
            {              
                echo
                '<td align="left" valign="top">' .
                  '<span class="boldinfo">' .
                  $y[$z] .
                  '</span>' .
                '</td>';    
            }
            if ($z >= strlen($y) - 1)
            { $z = 0; }
            else
            { $z++; }

            $c++;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Then I am not sure to understand want you want to do with your JS code but here's my new version of it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('.c3-legend-item-event').mouseover(function()
    {
        var colorKeyLength = $(this).closest("g").attr('class').length;
        var colorKey = $(this).closest("g").attr('class')[colorKeyLength-1];
        var colorKey2 = '';
        var spans = $('#tableexample .boldinfo');

        spans.each(function(index)
        {
            var txt = $(this).text();

            if (colorKey == txt)
            {
                // do something
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!